Determine the TextView size before drawing it on screen
I have a scrolling list of TextView elements, some of them contain more text (more lines), some less.
Over the right side of the scrolling list an image is drawn.
I want to add padding to each of the TextView elements, so that the text never overlaps with the image.
If I could measure the size of each TextView element before it is drawn to the screen, I would be able to adjust the padding so that the text doesn't overlap with the image.
The getHeight and getMeasuredHeight are not giving the correct values (getMeasuredHeight is invoked after a call to measure(0, 0)), the line count is always wrong before the elements are drawn.
Any ideas how to correctly predict the size of a TextView element before it is drawn, so that it's size could be modified in case it needs to?

Turns out one can measure the size of the TextView components by using
textView.measure(
          View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
          View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(someValue, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

After which textView.getMeasuredHeight() returns a correct value.
